# lisence of Lightning Web Component open source

Tags: lightning-web-components, open-source

I read LWC-open source is MIT lisece, and had a question.

Normaly(platform version),in order to access salesforce data,user must have salesforce lisence.

However, in open source version, user may not use salesforce platform but can access salesforce data, except salesforce lisence.

Is can be? I might not much understand about salesforce lisence system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a user to access Salesforce data, they need a salesforce.com license. The license of LWC open source only covers the UI/framework, and not Salesforce data. This allows developers to use LWC on their own site without any attachment to salesforce.com. If you still need access to Salesforce data, you need to have an appropriate salesforce.com license.

Comment: Thanks. I need some details about an appropriate license, where can I get info about it?

Comment: @Hayato You can see the [various license types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_understanding_license_types.htm&type=5). For pricing, you'll want to contact sales.